To examine whether the sequence $\frac{3n^2 + \sin n - 4}{2n^2 +3}$ is convergent or not using the $\epsilon$ definition.
The problem statement as mentioned in the title also is to examine whether the given sequence which is $$\frac {3n^2 + \sin n -4}{2n^2 + 3}$$ is convergent or not using the $\epsilon $ definition.
This was given to us in our assignment and and so I tried to solve it by proving it a cauchy sequence. So I took $|x_m - x_n |$ but I am not able to proceed any step further and totally unable to think of any setting. The equation obtained seems to provide no clue to me. Any help or hint will be highly appreciated. I have tried this one for quite a long and still unable to proceed.
Regarding whether it will converge or divergent well when applying through general technique $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = \frac {3}{2} $, got this by assuming that oscillating value of sin function is reduced to a very small value when divided by ${n^2}$.So it is rather convergent in my view.

Please edit to include your efforts.  If you believe it is convergent, what do you think it converges to?  If you don't believe it is convergent, do you think it oscillates or do you feel it goes to $\pm \infty$?

I don't think "it seems obvious that it is to be proved through cauchy criterion".

@AnneBauval well here it is  not appropriate to say that but that's the only thing we have been taught but ya OK I will change that.

@lulu I am editing it to include my efforts and thoughts...kindly bear with me till then.

I think that "using the $\epsilon $ definition" alludes to the definition of limit, which you must have been taught before Cauchy criterion. Haven't you also been taught theorems about the limit of a sum, a product, etc.?

Yes  we have been taught regarding those topics.

To prove the convergence of this sequence using the Cauchy Criterion, we need to show that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that for all $n,m\ge N$:
$$|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon$$
We start by considering the difference between two terms of the sequence.
$$|a_n-a_m|=\left|\frac{3n^2+\sin(n)-4}{2n^2+3}-\frac{3m^2+\sin(m)-4}{2m^2+3}\right|$$
We can use the triangle inequality
$$|a_n-a_m|=\left|\left(a_n-\frac{3}{2}\right)-\left(a_m-\frac{3}{2}\right)\right|\leq\left|a_n-\frac{3}{2}\right|+\left|a_m-\frac{3}{2}\right| $$
Now we want to find an upper bound for $\left|a_n-\frac{3}{2}\right|$ that depends on $n$ and similarly for $a_m$ so we can control $|a_n-a_m|$ by making $n$ and $m$ sufficiently large. We begin by computing the difference between $a_n$ and $\frac{3}{2}$:
$$\left|a_n-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\left|\frac{2n^2+\sin(n)-4}{2n^2+3}-\frac{3}{2}\right|$$$$\left|a_n-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\left|\frac{2n^2+\sin(n)-4}{2n^2+3}-\frac{3(2n^2+3)}{2(2n^2+3)}\right|$$$$\left|a_n-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\left|\frac{2(3n^2+\sin(n)-4)-3(2n^2+3)}{2(2n^2+3)}\right|$$$$=\left|\frac{6n^2 +2\sin(n)-8-6n^2-9}{2(2n^2+3)}\right|$$$$=\left|\frac{2\sin(n)-17}{4n^2+6}\right|$$$$=\left|\frac{\sin(n)-8.5}{2n^2+3}\right|$$
Since $-1\leq\sin(n)\leq1$,
$$-1-8.5\leq\sin(n)-8.5\leq1-8.5$$$$-9.5\leq\sin(n)-8.5\leq-7.5$$
Thus the absolute value of $\sin(n)-8.5$ is bounded by
$$|\sin(n)-8.5|\leq9.5$$ Now we have
$$\left|a_n-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\left|\frac{\sin(n)-8.5}{2n^2+3}\right|\leq\frac{|\sin(n)-8.5|}{2n^2+3}\leq\frac{9.5}{2n^2+3}$$
Similarly,
$$\left|a_m-\frac{3}{2}\right|\leq\frac{9.5}{2m^2+3}$$Now
$$|a_n-a_m|\leq\left|a_n-\frac{3}{2}\right|+\left|a_m-\frac{3}{2}\right| \leq\frac{9.5}{2n^2+3}+\frac{9.5}{2m^2+3}$$
To ensure $|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon$ we simply need
$$\frac{9.5}{2n^2+3}+\frac{9.5}{2m^2+3}<\epsilon$$
Since $n,m\geq N$, both terms on the left hand side must be less than or equal to $\frac{9.5}{2N^2+3}$. Thus it is sufficient to find $N$ such that
$$2\times\frac{9.5}{2N^2+3}<\epsilon$$$$\frac{9.5}{N^2+\frac{3}{2}}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$$$N^2+\frac{3}{2}>\frac{9.5\times2}{\epsilon}$$$$N^2>\frac{19}{\epsilon}-\frac{3}{2}$$$$N>\sqrt{\frac{19}{\epsilon}-\frac{3}{2}}$$
To satisfy the inequality we choose
$$\boxed{N=\left\lceil\sqrt{\frac{19}{\epsilon}-\frac{3}{2}}\right\rceil}$$
Thus the sequence is convergent, $q.e.d.$

As acknowledged by @Anne Bauval, there is a faster way to do it.
For anyone confused, when you have $|\sin(n)-8.5|\leq9.5$,
$$\left|a_n-\frac{3}{2}\right|\leq\frac{9.5}{2n^2+3}$$
To ensure $\left|a_n-\frac{3}{2}\right|<\epsilon$, we need
$$\frac{9.5}{2n^2+3}<\epsilon$$$$2n^2+3>\frac{9.5}{\epsilon}$$$$n^2>\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{9.5}{\epsilon}-3\right)$$$$n>\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{9.5}{\epsilon}-3\right)}$$
For any $\epsilon>0$, choose
$$\boxed{N=\left\lceil\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{9.5}{\epsilon}-3\right)}\right\rceil}$$
Then, for all $n\geq N$
$$\left|a_n-\frac{3}{2}\right|<\epsilon$$By the $\epsilon$-definition of convergence, the sequence $a_n$ does converge, and converges to $\frac{3}{2}$.

Cauchy criterion is overcomplicating things. $\left|a_n-\frac{3}{2}\right|\leq\frac{9.5}{2n^2+3}$ is sufficient to prove directly that the sequence converges to $3/2$.

Indeed, but I decided to go the full way as the poster mentioned that they desired a solution through the Cauchy criterion.

@Anne Bauval post has been updated

Better explain them that their "desire" is a misinterpretation of the exercise. Note also that $0<\frac{8.5-\sin n}{2n^2+3}<\frac{9.5}{2n^2}$.

Noted. I am also a big fan of your works on the Borsuk-Ulam theorem.

Hint. Use the double inequality $-1 \leqslant \sin n \leqslant 1$.

First find the value of the limit $\ell$ by rewriting your sequence
$$x_n=\frac {3 + \frac{\sin n}{n^2} -\frac4{n^2}}{2+\frac3{n^2}}$$ and applying the usual theorems about the limit of a sum, a product, etc., including the product of a bounded sequence by a sequence converging to $0$.
Then use as required the epsilon definition of the limit to (re)prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\ell$.
